# How to style custom formatted column to inherit height of row

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I have a custom formatted column in a Sharepoint List that changes the background color based on the content of the field.

When the content of another field in it's row is too large the background color does not fill the height of the row.

Is there a way to force the background color to inherit the height of it's row?

This is what is looks like with default heights in place. (background does not cover full height)

[image]

And this is what it looks like if I specify a height of 100px. (background is too large)

[image]

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "5px",
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "toString()",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField"
              ]
            },
            "GR"
          ]
        },
        "rgba(31, 73, 125, .2)",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "toString()",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField"
                  ]
                },
                "IDC"
              ]
            },
            "rgba(149, 144, 114, .2)",
            "inherit"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Things I have tried:

height: inherit;
height: 100%;
height: fill-content;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because it inherits the `min-height` from its parent element and the content “IDC/GR” is smaller than the minimum height, so the minimum height is applied.

[image]

If the content is larger than the minimum height, the `min-height` property has no effect.

[image]

As a workaround, you may need to set the height to a fixed length.